# Can't use knockout in Remote Twiitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am using twitter bootstrap, mvc, and knockout.  I have a modal that I am opening from a remote url that points to a page that deals with uploads.

I'm doing this like so:

```
<a class="btn btn-mini" data-toggle="modal"  data-bind="attr: { href: modalHref }" data-target="#UploadModal" >Uploads</a>


<div id="UploadModal" class="modal hide" style="display: none; " aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
    <h3>Upload</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body form-horizontal" style="padding:0;">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" href="#" data-bind="click: saveCount">Save</a>
</div>
</div>
```

The modal loads fine and everything inside of it works great.  Basically I have a fileuploader control where a user would post a file to me, I process it, and then I'm returning the column headers to process them.  Here is my ajax function on the form:

```
function uploadSubmit() {
$.ajax({
    url: '/Upload/UserSaveFileInfo/',
    type: 'post',
    async: false,
    data: ko.toJSON({
        UploadName: $("#uploadName").val(),
        UploadDescription: $("#uploadDescription").val(),
        Id:  $('#uploadId').val()
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {
        $("#uploader").hide();
        for( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
        {
            viewModel.RetRows.push({
                Id: ko.observable(result[i].Id),
                Header: ko.observable(result[i].Header),
                MatchedTo: ko.observable(result[i].MatchedTo),
                Values: ko.observable(result[i].Values),
                ColumnNumber: ko.observable(result[i].ColumnNumber)
            });
        }
        $("#matcher").show();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

}

This all works, but inside my remotely loaded modal I have some code where I'm trying to render a series of textboxes/spans from the returned data but it doesn't work.  I've tried to just look at other ko variables inside the modal and they don't show up, so it seems that the modal has no idea that knockout exists or knockout has no access to the modal content...  Is there a way to make the remote modal and ko sync up?

```
<!-- ko foreach: RetRows -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">
                Column <span data-bind="text: $data.ColumnNumber"></span>
            </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input data-bind="value: $data.MatchedTo" />
                <span class="help-block" data-bind="text: $data.value"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

I put this in the parent page and everything showed up.  So this seems to be a problem  with the remotely loaded content in the modal specifically.  Any ideas on how to fix this?  Perhaps there is a way I can attach the remote content via the bindingHandler?  Thanks for any insight anyone can provide.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the bindings to that modal.

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("remote_modal"));
```

Comment: Okay, after doing this:  
    $('#UploadModal').ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("myUploads"));
    });
  I'm getting some strange behavior.. I'm printing a variable in the modal to make sure I have access to the model but now after this happens the model is unapplied from the rest of the page.  i.e. I have controls that disappear.... i seem to be doing something wrong here.  when/where should i reapply the model to the remote modal?

Comment: yeah, try just `ko.applyBindings(viewModel)` in the same area. Remove the other applyBindings that I suggested previously.

Comment: It still does it with that... however, I made a new viewmodel and applied it to the div and it seems to work okay:                                  var modalModel = {
        SessionId: viewModel.SessionId(),
        RetCols: ko.observableArray([])
    };
    $('#UploadModal').ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
        ko.applyBindings(modalModel, document.getElementById("zupload"));
    });